# Error while using TryFrom for String in Rust

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement TryFrom for converting a string to a slice with the help of the following code shown below.

```
impl<const N: usize> TryFrom<String> for [u8; N] {
    type Error = &'static str;

    fn try_from(value: String) -> Result<[u8; N], Self::Error> {
        let val = value.as_bytes()[..];
        Ok(val)
    }
}
```

I am getting a compilation error when I call

```
let a = String::try_from("a".to_string()) 

impl<const N: usize> TryFrom<String> for [u8; N] {
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---------------^^^^^-------
    | |                    |                   |
    | |                    |                   this is not defined in the current crate because arrays are always foreign
    | |                    `std::string::String` is not defined in the current crate
    | impl doesn't use only types from inside the current crate
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to implement traits on external types because of the orphan rule.

See [Implementing a Trait on a Type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#implementing-a-trait-on-a-type):

> But we can’t implement external traits on external types. For example,
> we can’t implement the Display trait on Vec within our aggregator
> crate, because Display and Vec are both defined in the standard
> library and aren’t local to our aggregator crate. This restriction is
> part of a property called coherence, and more specifically the orphan
> rule, so named because the parent type is not present. This rule
> ensures that other people’s code can’t break your code and vice versa.
> Without the rule, two crates could implement the same trait for the
> same type, and Rust wouldn’t know which implementation to use.